# How can I get the index of a new ng-repeat item?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm fumbling my way through angular and I was wondering what is the best way to add a label with the current index.

Currently I have:

```
$scope.setups = [];

$scope.add = function () {
 $scope.setups.push({ 
    panelVal: "",
    spacingVal: "",
    lotsVal: "",
    panelPlaceholder: "Panels per lot",
    spacingPlaceholder: "Between frames (mm)",
    lotsPlaceholder: "Number of Lots"
    });
};

$scope.remove = function(array, index){
 array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

I have tried changing the add function to :

```
$scope.add = function (index) {
 $scope.setups.push({ 
    label: "Setup "+index,
    panelVal: "",
    spacingVal: "",
    lotsVal: "",
    panelPlaceholder: "Panels per lot",
    spacingPlaceholder: "Between frames (mm)",
    lotsPlaceholder: "Number of Lots"
    });
};
```

But index is undefined. I'm assuming I should be getting the index of setups. Or maybe even just the current length and incrementing it by one. What would be the best solution?

Comment: You can use `$index` to get the index like `<div ng-repeat="your in yourItem">
    <button ng-click="vm.functionName($index)"></button>
</div>`

Comment: Sorry I should have added that my button with ng-click is outside of the ng-repeat container.

Comment: Did it fix your problem ??

Answer (score 0):

I managed a work around if it helps someone else. To add the label I got the total length and then just added to the remove function to re-label on an item removal.

```
$scope.setups = [];

$scope.add = function (array, index) {

 arrlength = array.length;
 arrlength++;

array.push({ 
    label: "Setup "+arrlength,
    panelVal: "",
    spacingVal: "",
    lotsVal: "",
    panelPlaceholder: "Panels per lot",
    spacingPlaceholder: "Between frames (mm)",
    lotsPlaceholder: "Number of Lots"
    });
};

$scope.remove = function(array, index){
 array.splice(index, 1);

 labels = document.getElementsByClassName("setup-label");

 for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
 {
    labels[i].textContent="Setup "+i;
 }
}
```